# Difference between foo.join and foo.resolve? In webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dependency-injection, webpack, loader

I come from a ruby on rails background and I would like to know if I'm understanding the following code correctly...

currently my `webpack.config.js` looks like below...

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: [
    './app.js'
  ],
  ... etc
```

What would be the difference if I did

```
... (omitted code)

  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),

... etc
```

Does `resolve` look for the file in the directory and if it doesn't exist creates for me? Sort of like a `if defined` in `ruby`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path.join` is basically just string concatenation using the correct directory delimiters for the host operating system (usually `/` or `\`). `path.resolve` does the same thing *but also figures out the absolute path*, starting from the root directory of your system.

In your case, the resulting path will be the same because `__dirname` is already an absolute path, so simple concatenation with `path.join` produces the same result as `path.resolve` which guarantees an absolute path.

Neither method will create directories or files that don't exist - they will give you a path string regardless of whether anything can actually be reached there.

Edit: note that `path.join` and `path.resolve` are methods of the NodeJS `path` module specifically [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) - they are not general Javascript methods

Comment: thanks for the clarification.  I have another question, right now I've
 ```
entry: [
    './main.js',
  ]```

Comment: Sorry right out of time this is the error I'm getting ```ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/DS/Code/tryouts/react-project-setup/.babelrc: Error while parsing JSON - Expected ':' instead of '['```

Comment: Looks like your `.babelrc` isn't formatted correctly - possibly just a missing `:` after one of the keys. You can try copy and pasting the contents of `.babelrc` into http://jsonlint.com/ to get more specifics. JSON can't have any trailing commas before closing `{ }` or `[ ]`, so watch out for those.

Comment: Thanks @Mike McG, I got it working this morning and indeed it was a misplaces `:`inside `.babelrc`